# Set active tab on click, and remove previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a blade with tabs and when I click on tabs I want to remove an active class from tab from the previous one and add active one to the one that has been clicked. I decided to make a `setActive` function to make it all work

Changing tabs work perfectly, but from time to time it seems like some tabs still remain active, and suddenly I have 3 active tabs

Something like this happens to me:  [image: i.imgur.com/vbXf3rt.png]

```
 var setActive = function (sidebarItemId) {
        document.classList.remove("active")
        document.getElementById(sidebarItemId).classList.add("active")
    };
```

I also tried that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tab-pane").click(function () {
            $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
```

My blade:

```php
        @extends('person.person-dashboard')
@section('personContent')

    <div class="page-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row-no-margin">
                    <br>
                    @if ($message = Session::get('successRemove'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    @elseif($message = Session::get('failRemove'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    @elseif($message = Session::get('defaultRemoveError'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="cover-profile">
                    <div class="profile-bg-img">
                        <img class="profile-bg-img img-fluid" src="/files/assets/images/bg-img1-30opacity.png"
                             alt="bg-img">
                        <div class="card-block user-info">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <div class="img-hover">
                                            {{--Check if the picture is null, if so show default image--}}
                                            @if (is_null($person->avatar))
                                                <img class="img-fluid img-radius"
                                                     src="{{asset('storage/images/userImage/standard/default.png')}}"
                                                     width="150"
                                                     height="150" alt="user-img">
                                                <div class="img-overlay img-radius">
                                            <span>
                                                <a href="/person/profile/{{$person->person_id}}/{{$person->last_name}}/uploadfile"
                                                   class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                                    <i class="icofont icofont-edit"></i></a>
                                            </span>
                                                    @else
                                                        <img class="img-fluid img-radius"
                                                             src="{{asset('storage/images/userImage/standard').'/'.$person->avatar}}"
                                                             width="150"
                                                             height="150" alt="user-img">
                                                        <div class="img-overlay img-radius">
                                            <span>
                                                <a href="/person/profile/{{$person->person_id}}/{{$person->last_name}}/uploadfile"
                                                   class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                                    <i class="icofont icofont-edit"></i></a>
                                                <a href="/person/profile/{{$person->person_id}}/{{$person->last_name}}/remove"
                                                   class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-sm btn-danger waves-effect waves-light active"
                                                   name="delete-image" id="delete-image-button"
                                                   onclick="return confirm(trans('collaborators.areYouSure'))">
                                                    <i class="icofont icofont-ui-delete"></i></a>
                                            </span>
                                                            @endif
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="user-title">
                                                @if ($person->person_title == null)
                                                    <h2>{{$person->first_name}} {{$person->last_name}}</h2>
                                                @else
                                                    <h2>{{$person->person_title->name}} {{$person->first_name}} {{$person->last_name}}</h2>
                                                @endif
                                                <span>{{$person->mobile}}, {{$person->email}}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="cover-profile">
                        <div class="profile-bg-img">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-block user-info">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="media-body row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="user-title">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="pull-right cover-btn">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="tab-header card">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-tabs tab-timeline" role="tablist" id="mytab">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#personal" role="tab"
                               aria-expanded="true">{{trans('navigation.general')}}</a>

                            <div class="slide"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#practitioner" name="practitioner" role="tab"
                               aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.practitioner')}}</a>

                            <div class="slide"></div>
                        </li>
                        @isset($practitioner->practitioner_id)
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#availability" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.availability')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#absence" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.absence')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#contract" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.contract')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#training" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.training')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#history" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.history')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#access" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.access')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                @endisset
                @empty($practitioner->practitioner_id)
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#availability" role="tab"
                           aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.availability')}}</a>

                        <div class="slide"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#absence" role="tab"
                           aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.absence')}}</a>

                        <div class="slide"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#contract" role="tab"
                           aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.contract')}}</a>

                        <div class="slide"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#training" role="tab"
                           aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.training')}}</a>

                        <div class="slide"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#history" role="tab"
                           aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.history')}}</a>

                        <div class="slide"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#access" role="tab"
                           aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.access')}}</a>

                        <div class="slide"></div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            @endempty
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="personal" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <button id="edit-btn" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-editpanel btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light f-right">
                                <i class="icofont icofont-edit"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-block">
                            @include('person.profile.info-display')
                            @include('person.profile.info-edit')
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="practitioner" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true">
                    <div class="card">
                        @isset($practitioner->practitioner_id)
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <button id="edit-practitioner-btn" type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-editpanel btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light f-right">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-edit"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        @endisset
                        <div class="card-block">
                            @include('person.profile.practitioner.practitioner-display')
                            @isset($practitioner->practitioner_id)
                                @include('person.profile.practitioner.practitioner-edit')
                            @endisset
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="availability" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                    <div class="row">
                        {{trans('navigation.availability')}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="contract" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                    <div class="row">
                        {{trans('navigation.contract')}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="training" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                    <div class="row">
                        @include('person.profile.training.training')
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="absence" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                    <div class="row">
                        {{trans('navigation.absence')}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="history" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                    <div class="row">
                        {{trans('navigation.history')}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="access" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                    <div class="row">
                        {{trans('navigation.access')}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- tab content end -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @include("settings.remove-confirmation")

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/assets/css/custom-person-profile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/assets/css/remove-confirmation-modal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/assets/css/custom-j-forms.css">

    <script src="/files/js/views/person/person-profile.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/services/initialization.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/services/editButton.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/services/colors.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/modules/dataTable.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/modules/update.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/modules/create.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/modules/remove.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/modules/displayInfo.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/services/forms.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/services/validation.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/settings/setup-ajax-requests.js"></script>
    <script src="/files/js/services/rowReorderPersistence.js"></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Bootstrap already toggle the tab-pane active class when you click on nav-link

Comment: working fine with bootstrap - https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/cd3yazn6/1/

Comment: I think you forgot `bootstrap` `JS & CSS` files

Comment: something like this happens to me: https://i.imgur.com/vbXf3rt.png

Comment: add your `nav nav-tabs` inner HTML

Comment: added full blade

Comment: add `nav nav-tabs` screenshot generated HTML as you add above screen `something like this happens to me`

Comment: I would think that `document.classList.remove("active")` would cause an error, because `document` does not have a `classList` property...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>


<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```